# Possible Improvements for voting example present in Solidity Docs

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, gas

I am new to solidity so I just started with the voting example in the solidity docs.I am clear with the smart contract but there is a sub-section stating possible improvements -
"**Currently, many transactions are needed to assign the rights to vote to all participants. Can you think of a better way?**"

So,what changes do I need to make in the giveRightToVote function for reducing the transactions ?

```
function giveRightToVote(address voter) external {
        
        require(
            msg.sender == chairperson,
            "Only chairperson can give right to vote."
        );
        require(
            !voters[voter].voted,
            "The voter already voted."
        );
        require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }
```

Comment: So instead of assigning one by one what other options can you imagine?

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded a bit on the contract as per the proposed improvements.

Take a look at https://github.com/kristofvdj88/solidity-by-example/tree/main/voting

Comment: Hi kristofvdj88! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Link only answers are discouraged. It is better to put the main idea in the answer and use the link to expand the details.